# How to get two divs side by side? (Table structuring is old fashioned)

Tags: html, css

Okay. I know how to do this since there are multiple ways of doing the same thing, and i am also aware that this is a very basic question but often done wrong.

The point of making this question is to know the most appropriate/standard way that will not augment the positioning of the divs in any circumstance. I want the site structure to stand intact regardless of what can happen to the website (for ex. when the window is re-sized.)

I don't want to see lines and lines of styling, the least number of lines the better it is, if there is a way to implement it just as a div tag property, that would be fantastic.

[image]

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

```html
<!-- Main div -->
<div>
  <!-- first div, which need to be aligned on the left -->
  <div>
  </div>
  <!-- second div, which need to be aligned on the right,
parallel to the 1st div, not after the 1st div-->
  <div>
  </div>
  <!-- Closing tag of main div-->
</div>
```

I find this to be a great resource: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 2):

Here you go I believe this solution will have the least amount of lines

```css
div {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div>SAMPLE TEXT1</div>
  <div>SAMPLE TEXT2</div>
</div>
```

### Some other ways of having inline content:

1. inline-block
2. inline property
3. display: table-cell
4. Flexbox

First, I need to mention the simple pros and cons of the float element.

### Cons

- Any content below floated elements must have the clear property.

### Pros

- FULL browser support, this even works in IE6/7.

---

### inline-block

Here is a code snippet using inline-block according to the example given by Able Varghese:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div>SAMPLE TEXT1</div>
  <div>SAMPLE TEXT2</div>
</div>
```

### Cons

- Not as much browser support as the float solution.

### Pros

- Not as much markup.
- Easier to control and use.

---

### Inline

Here is an code snippet using `display: inline;`.

```css
div {
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div>SAMPLE TEXT1</div>
  <div>SAMPLE TEXT2</div>
</div>
```

### Cons

- As seen in the code snippet, inline obviously does not work as well as the other two solution.
  -IE6/7 support requires extra markup.

### Pros

- I honestly cant think of any. If any of you folks know one please post it in the comments. But for all general purposes, I dont think you should use this solution.

---

### Display: table-cell;

If there are any mistakes in this particular code snippet please mention so in the comments. I have never used this solution, I have only heard of it so this will be my first time using it.

Here is the code snippet

```css
div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div>SAMPLE TEXT1</div>
  <div>SAMPLE TEXT2</div>
</div>
```

### Cons

- If you were to use this solution, it would be no different than making your layout a very large table. (I believe everyone knows how that goes.)

### Pros

- Since this acts like a table, the divs "should" be easy to control, but I am inexperienced with this particular solution so dont make any bets that I'm correct with this reason.

---

### Flexbox

Here is a codesnippet using flexbox:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div>SAMPLE TEXT1</div>
  <div>SAMPLE TEXT2</div>
</div>
```

NOTE: The real power of flexbox is definitely not shown in this example here.

### Cons

- As of right now, Only a few browsers have implemented this solution.

### Pros

- This is an extremely powerful solution, as it is easy to control, use, and understand.

---

### There are many other solutions

These are the common solutions that I know of. If there are any more, (useless or not) please post it in the comment section.

### Summary:

All in all, its merely the developers choice. And with the three most commonly used solutions:(float, inline-block, and Flexbox). Its a choice whether to sacrifice Browser support over usability, or usability over browser support. Your choice.

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong about the previous explanation, I tested it and found that the left div is relative to the main div. if it's floating.

@HTMLNoob But the new issue is if you are floating the left div. and keep typing more content in the right div. until the horizontal size of the right div exceeds the left div., you'll see that this extra content will go below the left div. (it would not keep the right div the same width.

Comment: Ok, I will also take that into note. BTW do you mind if I post other ways of having the divs lnline with eachother?

Comment: dayum, I think this answer should win a pulitzer prize or something.

Comment: @HTMLNoob The answer above is a great example for having the left and right divs to align side by side and when window is re-sized horizontally the div(s) would move downward(in a responsive fashion).

 But how can we keep the divs fixed side by side(without changing their position) even when we try to re-size the window?? (horizontal re-sizing)

Comment: @AbleVarghese Here are a few examples that should fit your purposes. https://jsbin.com/gicecuwifu/edit?html,css,output -- Working on the others

Comment: And here is a probably the best solution: https://jsbin.com/wekerufusu/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion appropriate way would be to put the width of div1 and div2 in percentage in that case it would not create any problem even when you resize the window.

Comment: Do you know if doing so would keep the divs side by side even when you try to resize the window? (horizontal re-sizing)